# More from/to in key frames css

Tags: css

If I have:

```
@keyframes animateleft{from{left:-300px;opacity:0} to{left:0;opacity:1}}
```

Is it possible to make:

```
@keyframes animateLeftJump{
from{left:-300px;opacity:0} 
to{left:0;opacity:1}
from{left:0px;} 
to{right:100px;}
from{right:100px;}
to{left:0px;}
}
```

Like a little jumping left to right to left as main position?

Comment: you can divide the process using percentages: `0%{} 16%{} 32% {} etc` . check this out: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframes

Comment: @JosanIracheta so basically with % from 0-100 I define starting end ending proccess of my animation? Can I divide it by 1000 times? like 0.1%{}

Comment: Also one more thing, if I want to use transition from 0%-10% to be from top 0-50px with 3s transition and from 10%-90% 1s transition, how can I define that?

Comment: You can't define duration within the keyframe. You can only define the duration of the entire animation. If I wanted the first 10% of the keyframe to last 3s, then I would set the entire animation to last 30s. Just calculate the math.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like I mentioned in the comments, you should use percentages to divide the keyframe:

```
@keyframes my-animation{
  0%{}
  10%{}
  50%{}
  100%{}
}
```

Since the keyframe is split up into parts, you would have to calculate the duration of the entire animation for each part of the keyframe to last a desired duration.

So for example, you mentioned you wanted 0 - 10% to last 3 seconds, then the entire animation should last 30 seconds.

```
animation-name: my-animation;
animation-duration: 30s;
```

```css
div{
  background:red;
  animation:grow 30s infinite;
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  }
 @keyframes grow{
  10%{
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  }
  50%{
  width:400px;
  height:400px;
  }
  100%{
  width:100%;
  height:600px;
  }
  }
```

```html
<div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

NO,you can't use of :

```
@keyframes animateLeftJump{
  from{left:-300px;opacity:0} 
  to{left:0;opacity:1}
  from{left:0px;} 
  to{right:100px;}
  from{right:100px;}
  to{left:0px;}
}
```

**you said:** `Can I divide it by 1000 times? like 0.1%{}`

yes: but speed in change keyframes is high,you must set `animation-duration` and `keyframes` with accuracy.

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #000;
  animation: test 2s infinite;
  color: #FFF;
}

@keyframes test {
  0.01% {background-color:orange }
  0.08% {background-color: blue}
  0.15% {background-color: green}
  0.20% {background-color: red}
  0.25% {background-color: skyblue}
}
```

```html
<p>It's so fast that you can not see some of the changes</p>
<div>See change Keyframes</div>
```